# facebook like / send button slide out drops behind body / hidden

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-like

When people click on the like button or 'send' button in my header, the new 'slider' action drops down but is dropping down behind the content below the header.

I've tried giving the facebook div a z-index of 1000 but nothing seems to work. To see the error in action, press like or send on on the site http://healthysurprise.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I fond one think if y remove `**overflow:hidden**` in `.navbar-inner`  css class than your problum is shortlist

As like it

```
.navbar-inner{
overflow:hidden;  // Remove this line in your css file 
}
```